# Is prototype.js still relevant?

Tags: jquery, prototyping

I'm developing a web application which I started on about 2 years ago. It is an AJAX-heavy single page design and prototype solved problems where I didn't want to reinvent the wheel. I am using a couple of third-party tools that depends on prototype, namely okonet modalbox, protofish tooltips, scriptaculous, My own use of prototype is relegated to simple operations such as reading input values and creating elements.

My concern started with the lack of updates for prototype and prima facie evidence on the Internet. If you search for something JScript related jquery is mentioned a lot and prototype hardly at all.

Lately it seems that jquery is the toolkit of choice and prototype is stagnating. Should I make the switch to jquery?

Answer (score 5):

I can't say anything about prototype stagnating or not, but jQuery is definitely worth the switch.  It is a very robust and growing library, with tons of add ons and libraries out there that use it.

Ruby on Rails recently made it the de-facto standard after dropping all standards in the previous release.

Answer (score 0):

Prototype and Scriptaculous are both used extensively at my job.

Apparently, the next major version of Prototype is going to stop using DOM extension - and given that this was the basis Prototype was originally developed around, it's not surprising that it's taking a while for a new release to come about.